# How can I formulate this simple mathematical riddle into a computable Wolfram Language query?

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

I'm trying to formulate the below question into a computable wolfram language solution, but can't seem to get it right.

Question:

Place three piles of matches on a table, one with 11 matches, the second with 7, and the third with 6. You are to move matches so that each pile holds 8 matches. You may add to any pile only as many matches as it already contains, and all the matches must come from one other pile. For example, if a pile holds 6 matches, you may add 6 to it, no more or less. You have three moves.

What I've tried:

```
pile1 = 11; 
pile2 = 7; 
pile3 = 6; 
moves = 3; 

findSolution[pile1_, pile2_, pile3_, moves_] := 
  Module[{solutions}, 
   solutions = 
    FindInstance[{pile1 + x1 == 2*x2, pile2 + x2 == 2*x3, 
      pile3 + x3 == 2*x1, x1 >= 0, x2 >= 0, x3 >= 0, x1 <= pile1, 
      x2 <= pile2, x3 <= pile3}, {x1, x2, x3}, Integers, moves]; 
   If[solutions == {}, {}, {pile1 - x1, pile2 - x2, pile3 - x3} /. 
     solutions[[1]]]]; 

findSolution[pile1, pile2, pile3, moves]
```

This give `{}` or no solution.

However, there does exist a solution. The solution is:

1. Move 7 matches from the pile with 11 matches to the pile with 7 matches. The piles now contain 4, 14, and 6 matches.
2. Move 6 matches from the pile with 14 matches to the pile with 6 matches. The piles now contain 4, 8, and 12 matches.
3. Move 4 matches from the pile with 12 matches to the pile with 4 matches. The piles now contain 8, 8, and 8 matches.

Is there a way to formulate the question so that this is computable with Wolfram Language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution. In every step, there are only 3 movements: 1-2,1-3,2-3. And there are only 3 steps. In every step we do all possible moves and call the next step:

```
piles = {6, 7, 11, {}};
moves = Subsets[{1, 2, 3}, {2}];

move[p_, count_] := Module[{},
  If[p[[1]] == p[[2]] == p[[3]] == 8, Return[p[[4]]]];
  If[count == 4, Return[]];
  res = Reap[
     Do[
      t = moves[[i]];
      t = SortBy[t, p[[#]] &];
      pt = p;  pt[[t[[2]]]] -= p[[t[[1]]]]; pt[[t[[1]]]] *= 2;
      AppendTo[pt[[4]], t];
      res = move[pt, count + 1];
      If[res != {}, Sow[res]];
      , {i, 3}]
     ][[2]];
  Flatten[res, 2]
  ]

move[piles, 1]

{{2, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 1}}
```

This returns the moves: 3->2, 2->1, 1->3

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach. Looking for path length 3 solution from state {11,7,6} to state {8,8,8}. It is messy.

Functions to create graph:

```
f[{a_, b_, c_}] := Module[{p, v},
  p = {{2 a, b - a, c}, {2 a, b, c - a}, {a - b, 2 b, c}, {a, 2 b, 
     c - b}, {a - c, b, 2 c}, {a, b - c, 2 c}};
  v = Cases[p, Table[_?Positive, 3]];
  DirectedEdge[{a, b, c}, #] & /@ v]
g[x_] := Module[{v}, v = x[[All, 2]]; Join @@ (f /@ v)]
```

Solving riddle and visulaizing solution

```
q = f[{11, 7, 6}];
grp = Union[Join @@ NestList[g, q, 2]];
fp = FindPath[grp, {11, 7, 6}, {8, 8, 8}];
de = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[fp[[1]], 2, 1];
HighlightGraph[grp, {fp[[1]], de}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A variation of ubpdqn's approach using [`NestGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestGraph.html):

```
step = {Sort@{#3 - #, #2, 2 #}, Sort@{#3 - #2, 2 #2, #}} & @@  Sort[#] &;

ng = SimpleGraph @ NestGraph[step, {{11, 7, 6}}, 3, VertexLabels -> Automatic];


HighlightGraph[ng, 
 Subgraph[ng, First @ FindPath[ng, {11, 7, 6}, {8, 8, 8}]], 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", 
 GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 16]
```

[image]

If we did know that 3 steps is sufficient:

```
ng5 = NestGraph[step, {{11, 7, 6}}, 5, VertexLabels -> Automatic];

HighlightGraph[SimpleGraph @ ng5, 
 Subgraph[ng5, FindShortestPath[ng5, {11, 7, 6}, {8, 8, 8}]], 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", 
 GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", VertexLabelStyle -> 16]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Like the graph layout and approach. More thoughtful than my rushed effort.

Answer (score 2):

```
Remove["Global`*"]

(* Moves are pairs e.g {a,b} where a!=b, and moves matches from pileA to pileB *)
allMoves = Permutations[{1, 2, 3}, {2}];

(* Move the 'from' pile to the 'to' pile *)
move[piles_, {from_, to_}] := 
 Module[{p = piles}, p[[to]] += piles[[to]]; p[[from]] -= piles[[to]];p]

(* Do a sequence of moves starting with initial pile 'init' *)
evaluateMoveSequence[moves_, init_] := FoldList[move, init, moves]

(* Moves are valid if you are moving a positive amount, and it doesn't leave a negative 'from' pile *)
validMoves[piles_] := 
 Select[allMoves, 
  piles[[#[[1]]]] >= piles[[#[[2]]]] && piles[[#[[2]]]] > 0 &]

(* Solve a matches game, returning the first move sequence found up to maxdepth that gives us 'target' pile.
 We cache pile states as we go to avoid repeatedly searching the same states *)
matchesGameSearch[pilesInit_, maxdepth_, target_] := 
 Module[{cache = CreateDataStructure["HashSet"], search},
  search[piles_, depth_, moves_] := 
   Module[{valid = RandomSample@validMoves[piles]},
    (* If we've got the target, 
    Throw the answer which will get us out of the recursion and give the move path to Catch *)
    If[piles == target, Throw[moves]];
    (* Terminate if we've exceeded depth, 
    or if we've already seen this state, 
    or if there are no valid moves *)
    If[depth == 0 || cache["MemberQ", piles] || valid == {}, 
     Return[],
     cache["Insert", piles];
     (* search all valid moves *)
     search[move[piles, #], depth - 1, Append[moves, #]] & /@ valid;
     (* If we got here, we failed *)
     Return[{}];
     ]
    ];
  Catch[search[pilesInit, maxdepth, {}]]
  ]

initpiles = {11, 7, 6};
moveseq = matchesGameSearch[initpiles, 3, {8, 8, 8}]
evaluateMoveSequence[moveseq, initpiles]
```

Comment: If you employ sorting like in Daniel's answer then you'll get a more efficient search as there are 3 moves instead of 6.